# Where is Choice invoked in the following recursive definition?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

**Lemma**: Let $\rho$ be a signed measure that omits the value $+\infty$. If $\rho(G)>0$, then there exists a subset $E\subseteq G$ such that $E$ is totally positive and $\rho(E)>0$.

**Proof**: Let $E_1=G$. If $E_1$ is totally positive, then there is nothing to prove; so suppose that $E_1$ is NOT totally positive. Then $\exists F\subseteq E_1$ such that $\rho(F)>\rho(E_1)$. In particular, the set $J_1=\{n\in\mathbb{N}: \exists F\subseteq E_1(\rho(F)\geq\rho(E_1)+\frac{1}{n})\}$ is nonempty, thus has a smallest element $n_1$. Choose $E_2\subseteq E_1$ such that $\rho(E_2)\geq\rho(E_1)+\frac{1}{n_1}$. Now, if $E_2$ were totally positive, then the proof is complete. Otherwise, let $n_2$ be the smallest element of $J_2=\{n\in\mathbb{N}: \exists F\subseteq E_2(\rho(F)\geq\rho(E_2)+\frac{1}{n})\}$. **Continuing by induction produces a decreasing sequence of measurable sets $\mathbf{(E_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}}$ such that** $\mathbf{\rho(E_{i+1})\geq\rho(E_i)+\frac{1}{n_i}}$.

I am almost certain that *Choice* has been invoked somewhere in the definition of $(E_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$, but I just can't put my finger on exactly where. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be using dependent choice in asserting you can complete the sequence. Induction only tells you that you can construct finite sequences of arbitrarily large length, it does not give you an infinite sequence.

Comment: Well, the word "choose" (in "choose $E_2\subseteq E_1$" and more generally the implicit "choose $E_{i+1}\subseteq E_i$") stands out as an obvious candidate ...

Comment: Thank you both! I think the fact that not only is the definition recursive but it also involves arbitrary choices is what made it a bit harder for me to unravel.

Comment: One point people often miss is that while AC is not required to make any finite number of choices, and then it feels that induction will yield *all* choices, what one proves with induction is only that for all $n$ there exist $E_i$, $i\leq n$, satisfying the properties. But what you want is the existence   of $E_i$ for all $i$. If you write it out carefully, you'll see induction proves a statement of the form "for all $n$ there exist M such that P(M,n) holds", whereas what you actually want is "there exists M such that for all $n$ P(M,n) holds", which is not implied by the former.

Comment: In the statement you're proving there is no quantifer on $G$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for letting me know! Fixed.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Excellent point.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_1=\{F\subseteq G: \exists n\in\mathbb{N}(\rho(F)\geq\rho(G)+\frac{1}{n})\}$, $A_2=\{F'\subseteq G: \exists F\in A_1[F'\subseteq F\land\exists n\in\mathbb{N}(\rho(F')\geq \rho(F)+\frac{1}{n})]\}$, etc. Then one can invoke the *Dependent Choice* to show the existence of a sequence $(A_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$, where the total relation $R$ on $\mathscr{A}=\{A_i: i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is $$A_i R A_j\ \text{if and only if}\ \forall F'\in A_{j}\exists F\in A_i[F'\subseteq F\land\exists n\in\mathbb{N}(\rho(F')\geq\rho(F)+\frac{1}{n})].$$ Further, one can invoke the existence of a *Choice Function* $c: \mathscr{A}\to\overset{\infty}{\underset{i=1}{\bigcup}}A_i$ to show the existence of a sequence $(E_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\forall i(E_i\in A_i)$. Indeed, the definition of $(E_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ in the proof of the lemma requires even stricter conditions, namely $\rho(E_{i+1})\geq\rho(E_i)+\frac{1}{n_i}$, where $n_i$ is the smallest element of each $J_i$, hence further argument is still needed.

Comment: I would rephrase a bit. While it is true that your construction *invokes* (at least a weak form of) AC, when you say "must have relied on the Choice Axiom" you seem to be asserting that *any* existence proof **must** invoke the AC in some form. There are such situations, but that requires proving that one can *deduce* the general AC (or a weaker form) from the existence of the objects in question. E.g. showing AC is **required** (and not merely "usually used") to prove every vector space has a basis requires showing the latter implies AC.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Another excellent point.